Easy way to augment the spell check dictionary in Lyx
I use Lyx for scientific writing and it rejects many common words such as hyphenated words. Googling "expand Lyx dictionary" led to a large number of obscure returns, mostly based on Windows. I use Linux. How can I download a scientific dictionary and replace my dictionary with it?

Welcome to TeX.SE! Have you asked the support of Lyx?

Spell check is made by Enchant or so (in my Lyx 2.3.7 in Debian is the only option available, but I saw others in  the past, check it in the preferences). If you do not Enchant in your Linux, in Debian can be  installed with:
$ sudo apt install enchant-2

If you have Enchant working well with LyX, when you add some word with Add to personal dictionary the new word is stored in  ~/.config/enchant/en_US.dic (or es_ES.dic, or whatever,  depending of the language that you set for the document).
The .dic files are just plain text files with one word per line, so it is easy edit to add a bunch of your own particular scientific jargon with any text editor. From where obtain a good list of scientific words is another story.
Probably you have also  system-wide  dictionaries in /usr/share/hunspell/or so, but you shouldn't touch these files that can be overwritten with any update.
